# PDF with named destinations hosted on webserver doesn't navigate to some destinations via URL anchor

Tags: pdf, uri, acrobat

I have a PDF that contains named destinations. It is hosted on a web server. When I navigate to the PDF using #nameddest=[named destination name] or #[named destination name] appended to the URL, most of the destinations work, and they are properly navigated to; but, there are some that don't. There does not appear to be any difference between the ones that do and the ones that don't. The naming convention for the destinations is standard, all lowercase, with words divided by a dash "-". I receive the same result in both Edge and Chrome. Double-clicking on the destinations that do not work in the browser in Acrobat Pro DC work as expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: No code. I wasn't sure where else to post. I also posted in Adobe's forums. This is strictly an issue with opening a PDF at particular named destination with a URL anchor in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post so just for newer searches a few pointers, Adobe have a habit of overlapping jargon so Named Destinations can be other than URL base ones, however Here I confine best practice for historic www/file.pdf#fragments as used by browsers or acrobat command line.

Named Destinations are not the visible items you see in the Navigation Sidebar (those are outline bookmarks) the destinations here are internal bookmark targets that are not displayed, (unless using an editor sidebar).

There are several rules that can trip you up **Rule 1 no spaces**

`nameddest=Chapter5.8.somelink.tag`

**Should fail** the permitted length was up to 32 characters and `nameddest=` uses 10 so max length = 22 for the name part.

Another possible fail point is perhaps using section numbers.

`nameddest=Chapter5.10`

Numerics should in theory not have more than one digit after the decimal point.

Avoid characters other than a-Z and numbers and resist any punctuation (=&# are reserved but others cause problems too) consider using `-` for clear separation such as

`nameddest=Chapter-5-10-1`